# MSYS2 inferior shell in Emacs on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, emacs, msys2

Trying to launch an inferior shell (M-x shell) in Emacs on Windows that connects to MSYS2.

I found this snippet from [Mastering Emacs - Running Shells in Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview) Mastering Emacs, and adapted it:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "D:/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe")
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--login" "-i")) <- Have also tried -c, and without "--login"
(setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name)
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-strip-ctrl-m)
```

I get the following:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
]0;~
me@computer MSYS ~
$
```

So I have some extra goofy characters and an inappropriate command passed to the MSYS shell, but this is progress! MSYS2 + Emacs on Windows would be AMAZING.

Comment: An *inferior* shell, you say? You must be looking for `csh` (pax ducks for cover).

Comment: Are you sure that `D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/bash.exe` is the correct path? I think a non-existent executable is the most likely reason for getting the error you are seeing.

Comment: @DKrueger You're right! I now have Emacs talking through MSYS, but not quite 'cleanly'. It was in D:/msys64/usr/bin. Feeeeeeeling stupid on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `-i` for Bash. It means interactive, so Bash attempts to configure terminal with `ioctl` which is nonsense for native Windows Emacs. Strip `-i` in native Emacs when you are using MSYS2 Bash.

Comment: 5 years later. This is why Emacs will win, in the end, over all other editors.

Comment: It seems we need to suffer from error message that is triggered by `-i` because the option is responsible for activating interactive mode: thus loading of  `~/.bashrc`!